# keras.utils.layer_utils and keras.utils.generic_utils equivalent in tf.keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

So i've been following this guide (https://towardsdatascience.com/faster-r-cnn-object-detection-implemented-by-keras-for-custom-data-from-googles-open-images-125f62b9141a) when trying to implement my custom dataset for object detection with faster r-cnn. So in the source code to train the dataset, here are all the list of all Keras-related modules.

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD, RMSprop
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D, TimeDistributed
from keras.engine.topology import get_source_inputs
from keras.utils import layer_utils
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
from keras.objectives import categorical_crossentropy

from keras.models import Model
from keras.utils import generic_utils
from keras.engine import Layer, InputSpec
from keras import initializers, regularizers
```

because i use the  Tensorflow specific implementation of the Keras API, I convert all these above keras module to tensorflow.keras and so on. There's some minor adjustment like these:

```
from keras.engine.topology import get_source_inputs
```

to

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import get_source_inputs
```

I've found most of the tensorflow.keras equivalent module, expect for two of these line:

```
from keras.utils import layer_utils

from keras.utils import generic_utils
```

I can't even find keras.utils documentation for those two modules on https://keras.io/api/utils/
How do i convert those two module into tensorflow.keras? I'm currently running tensorflow version 2.1.0 locally. And if there's now way that I can't import these module, is there any solution? I'm planning to train my data using my gpu locally.

Comment: Kindly refrain from including code that is blatantly irrelevant to the question (edited out).

Answer (score 2):

In tensorflow 2.x, you can use

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import layer_utils


from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import generic_utils
```

Answer (score 2):

With current version of Tensorflow (2.8.2), the following code in working fine for me. So the above code can be changed with this code

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD, RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D,     TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras.utils import get_source_inputs 
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import layer_utils 
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import generic_utils
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer, InputSpec
from tensorflow.keras import initializers, regularizers
```