Cannot find Keras.utils.layer_utils
How do I resolve the error:
"No module called layer_utils"

When I try to install or import it from Keras or Tensorflow, I receive the error message that says it does not exist.
I am following a tutorial that installs various dependencies from a requirements.txt file, but probably some things are missing.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69711729/7976758 Found in https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-google-coop&q=layer_utils&cx=005305742766141300566:jc9gtvxee8o Also see https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface/issues/97 ,

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please try  by using these commands from keras.utils import layer_utils ,from
tensorflow.keras.utils import layer_utils. Let us know if you are still facing the issue . Thank you.
